# Is there a Chrome page action icon maximum update rate?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the icon of a page action in a Chrome extension I'm building. When you click on the page action, the icon should turn into an animated loading wheel (@24 fps ideally). To do it, I use canvas to draw out the loading wheel in the background page, and use `window.setInterval` to redraw the canvas and update the icon.

Problem is I'm unable to get anywhere near 24fps, even for a relatively simple 19x19 canvas with a loading wheel comprised of only 8 2pixel-diameter circles arranged in a ring. I want to know if there's a frame rate limit set in Chrome, either explicitly (e.g. set by Google) or implicitly (e.g. due to `pageAction.setIcon()` being slow).

Here's what it looks like in action: http://quick.as/9zgls3je

As a sanity check here's how it looks when rendered in the DOM: http://quick.as/6Jolf8RV

Here's my code:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  startLoad();
});

function startLoad() {

  // setting up the canvas:

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var tab = chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tabId = tabs[0].id;
    var positions = [];
    var resolution = 10;
    var radius = 6;
    var thickness = 2;
    for (var i=0; i<resolution; i++) {
      var x = canvas.width/2 + radius*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/resolution);
      var y = canvas.height/2 + radius*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/resolution);
      positions[i] = [x,y];
    }
    var darkness = 0;

    // updates the canvas and the pageAction icon, supposedly @ 10fps

    window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log("new frame");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      for(var i=0; i<resolution; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(positions[i][0], positions[i][1], thickness, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + darkness + "," + darkness + "," + darkness + ")";
        ctx.fill();
        darkness += Math.round(255/(resolution-2));
        if(darkness>255) {darkness = 0}
      }
      chrome.pageAction.setIcon({imageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19), tabId: tabId});
    }, 100);
    console.log("icon set");
  });
}
```

Comment: What DO you get instead?

Comment: This is what it looks like: http://quick.as/9zgls3je

Comment: There are examples that animate the browserAction quite smoothly, for instance [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animated-icons/opohemjajipifffggpheepndmcmnddaf). The issue may be with pageActions.

Comment: Useful... I will look at that and see if the same script animates a pageAction decently, that should give me my answer. Thanks Xan